# Sent email from the program

Tags: c#, winforms, email

I already created the application in windows forms c# which ready to be use by another user in another computer, but i am aware there will be an error occurred when run my program (because i didn't have enough time to check everything), so i decided to let users find the bug and report to me through email.

I have a button "Report a Problem", but how do i when users click that button, it will open the Microsoft Outlook and automatically filled up the Received Email or "To" with my own email?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
Process.Start("mailto:your@emailaddress.com");
```

This will prompt Windows to create a new mail using the default email provider (which will most likely be Microsoft Outlook if it's installed).

To use this method, please add:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

to the top of your code file.

Comment: There is no Process.Start in there Mr Baldrick

Comment: It's in the System.Diagnostics namespace, see edited answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Diagnostics.Process.Start("mailto: senderEmail")`

And it'll work only if you have outlook as your default email client

Answer (score 1):

Namespace : using System.Diagnostics;

```
Process.Start("mailto:revanayyamca@gmail.com");
```